# Parse timestamp as date time and perform function

Tags: python, csv, parsing, timestamp

I am unexperienced with Python and am trying to parse all timestamps of the following csv as datetime objects in order to then perform functions on them (e.g. find timestamp differences etc.).

However, I can parse single lines but not the whole timestamp column. I am getting a 'KeyError: '2010-12-30 14:32:00' for the first date of the timestamp column, when reaching the line below my 'not working' comment.

Thanks in advance.

```
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    import pandas as pd

    from dateutil.parser import parse

    csvFile = pd.read_csv('runningComplete.csv')
    column = csvFile['timestamp']

    column = column.str.slice(0, 19, 1)
    print(column)

    dt1 = datetime.strptime(column[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    print(dt1)

    dt2 = datetime.strptime(column[2], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    print(dt1)

    dt3 = dt1 - dt2

    print(dt3)

    for row in column:
    print(row)


    Not working: 

    for row in column:
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(column[row], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Try `for row in range(len(column))`.

Comment: Thanks, but now I get "TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series". I have really been trying various things and I always get either error -.-

Comment: Can You add outputs for those `print` commands, please?

Comment: @CodeIsland: [Edit] your Question and show the output of `print(column)` **after** `column = csvFile['timestamp']` of the first **three** rows.

Comment: Thank you! It is working now with the original hint by Fejs "for row in range(len(column)". There was a further bug I did not see at first that caused the TypeError.